# Relative Auto Layout Constraints in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

In code I can set constraints between two objects so that they are relative...

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:item1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:item2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:0.9
                                                       constant:0]];
```

Or so they have a constant difference...

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:item1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:item2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:-30]];
```

Or event so they relate different attributes of the same item...

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:item1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:item1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];
```

Is it possible to apply these type of constraints using Interface Builder?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Width equals height" constraint in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167607/width-equals-height-constraint-in-interface-builder)

Comment: Ah, couldn't find that. Thanks. Fingers crossed for WWDC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible now in XCode 5.1.

This is a change from 5.0. When you add for example an "Equal Widths" constraint you can now go to the inspector, there's a new field where you can input the multiplier value (among other new things), thus creating a proportionally sized view which can be related to its container or some other view within the hierarchy.

Comment: Hmm... is this a change from 5.0? Will be awesome if it is.

Comment: Yes it is a change from 5.0. When you add for example an "Equal Widths" constraint you can now go to the inspector, there's a new field where you can input the multiplier value (among other new things), thus creating a proportionally sized view which can be related to its container or some other view within the hierarchy

Answer (score 3):

It's possible in interface builder. Select the IB item in question and inspect the constraints on it. Select and edit will reveal the multiplier settings of the constraint.

[image: AutolayoutRelativeMultiplierInterfaceBuilder]

Comment: It is now yep. They added it in the latest release of Xcode. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can enter in percentage as well such as 50%  The side arrows allow incrementing and decrementing by .1 or by 1%

Setting a % multiplier (constant 0) relative of the superview (or image view) center x,y is handy to allow a label or textfield to track a specific place in a view or image regardless of it's final position or scale.

You can see what the constraints do by selecting main view and going to:
Editor -> Resolve auto layout issues -> Update Frames and the different elements will move based on their constraints.

Sometimes IB updates on the fly but usually not.

Comment: You can now but it was only as part of Xcode 5 which wasn't out yet :-) thanks :-)