# how can I make in auto layout that view1 height will be = 3.7 view2 height?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have `view1` and `view2` on screen.
how can I make in auto layout  that  view1 height will be = 3.7 view2 height?
Maybe that can be done by adding constraints in code. But I want to know all solutions.

Also how It can be done that view1 height will be = 3 view2 height? I think that can be done by adding 2 more views `(viewAdditon1, viewAdditon2)` . so that

view1 ,viewAdditon1, viewAdditon2 will have equal  height. also view1.y top  =  view2.y top. and also viewAdditon1.y bottom  =  view2.y bottom.
viewAdditon1.y bottom  = viewAdditon2.y top.  viewAdditon2.y bottom  = view1.y top.

Also question . How to make a square view? Or how to make that view1 height = 0.7 * view2 width?

Also question . How to make space between view1 buttom and view2 top = 1/4 view3 height? I know that can be done using view4 for this space. so view4 height =  1/4 view3 height . and view4 will be between  view1 and view2. mabe there is other solutions?

Comment: Are you asking  for a solution that does it in Interface Builder?

Comment: I am asking for any solution.

Comment: This question is way too broad.  One question per question, please.  Your question shouldn't be a laundry list of questions.  Effectively, you're asking for a complete auto layout tutorial.  And while I'm glad you're seeking these answers, the form of this question isn't even remotely a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Either present a single, specific problem, and seek detailed help resolving that problem, or go find Apple's auto layout documentation and take some time to figure it all out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use autolayout to set a view 2/3 of the other view by storyboard：

Assuming that you have set all contains except height of this two views.

Now control drag from `view2` to `view1`. Selected `Equal Heights`.

[image]

And then select this contains you added just now. Change the `Multiplier` to `2/3`.

[image]

That's all.

[image]

Hope this can help someone.

Comment: Also question . How to make a square view? Or how to make that view1 height = 0.7 * view2 width?

Comment: @userInStackoverflow here you can find out how to set square view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167607/width-equals-height-constraint-in-interface-builder and if feel free to up vote my answer, thank you!

Comment: thanks again. I am not too cool user for vote up. Also question . How to make space between view1 buttom and view2 top = 1/4 view3 height? I know that can be done using view4 for this space. so view4 height = 1/4 view3 height . and view4 will be between view1 and view2. mabe there is other solutions?

Comment: @userInStackoverflow yes using a hidden view4 is currently the best way to achieve that.