# Alignment of the View using AUTOLAYOUT AND SIZECLASSES

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

How to align the trailing edge of the one view to the horizontal centre of the other view.

._____________
|1____________|
.______________________________
|2_____________________________|

I want something like above. I always want the view1 to the half of the width of the view2.

Comment: Set the leading to be the same and the width of view1 to be 50% of the width of view2?

Comment: Thanx for reply. But how to do this?

Comment: I got the solution from the following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814710/how-can-i-make-in-auto-layout-that-view1-height-will-be-3-7-view2-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold CTRL then click and drag from view1 to view2. Let go of the mouse click and a menu should pop up. Choose both "Left" and "Equal Widths".

Then click the edit button of the Equal Width constraint and change the multiplier to 0.5 (50%).

[image: Multiplier]

Answer (score 3):

**Click both UI elements you want to align and align their trailing edges**

[image]

**Select one of the two elements and double click on the newly created constraint**

[image]

**Change the Edge of the item that you want to be bigger (in my case SecondItem) and set its edge to be CenterX**

[image]

**update the frames and voila**

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. I was unaware that you could align to the center like that.

Comment: You can align everything to anything :D It actually is pretty powerful!