# Equal width option not showing in Xcode 11.1

Tags: ios, xcode11.1

I have installed Xcode 11.1 version recently and it is not showing an equal width option. I have dragged a view to the super view of the controller but I haven't found equal width option like in previous versions of Xcode. Please find below the screen which I have tried.

[image]

Comment: See this question (answer) also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58115770/2399348

Answer (score 1):

Finally after trying many times found the solution. Instead of dragging to the main view dragged to safe area of the main view then equal width option came.